# List of Lists of Object referencing same object in Python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and so I'm not extremely familiar with the syntax and the way things work exactly. It's possible I'm misunderstanding, but from what I can tell from my code this line:

```
largeBoard = [[Board() for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

is creating 9 references to the same Board object, rather than 9 different Board objects. How do I create 9 different Board objects instead?

When I run:

```
largeBoard = [[Board() for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]        
x_or_o = 'x'      
largeBoard[1][0].board[0][0] = 'g' # each Board has a board inside that is a list 
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            for l in range(3):
                print largeBoard[i][j].board[k][l]
```

I get multiple 'g' that is what made me think that they are all references to the same object.

Comment: It is indeed creating 9 different `Board` objects. Try printing the `id` of each object in `largeBoard`.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't create different objects?

Comment: They are all different objects.

Comment: You might need to show us the code for your `Board` class... perhaps it is built around a singleton-like pattern that simply returns (a reference to) the same object every time you call it's constructor...

Comment: Maybe you accidentally used a class attribute for `board` instead of setting `self.board` in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have it reversed: you *are* creating 9 independent `Board` instances there. If you had something like

```
largeBoard = [[Board()] * 3] * 3
```

*then* you would only have a single instance. This is the root of a common mistake that many Python newcomers make.

`[X for i in range(3)]` evaluates `X` once for each `i` (3 times here) whereas `[X] * 3` evaluates `X` only once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is your Board class (I was able to reproduce your error using this):

```
class Board:
    board = [[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
```

To fix this, you need to create an `__init__()` function to initialize your board so that each instance has its own board:

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
```

Then you should only see one "g".  [Here is the code in ideone that compares the classes.](http://ideone.com/tz9CLT)